# How can I implement simple robust regression?

Tags: least-squares, regression

I have many datasets like this:

[image]

to which I am trying to fit lines:
$$
y = a + bx
$$

However as you can see there are some outliers in each dataset. The number varies from data set to dataset.

I am looking for a simple but good way to filter out these outliers.

So far I am doing this:

1. Calculate a and b from all points (using Eigen: QR decomposition).
2. Find which point is the furthest from this line and remove it.
3. Calculate a and b from the new set of points.

I then repeat 2 and 3 until I have removed 10% of the points.

Comment: That seems like a reasonable method. What is your specific question? If you are asking about "the best" method, you need to state the requirements of your application by which "best" can be quantified.

Comment: You might be interested in this question: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/89773/using-nearest-neighbor-in-ransac